# How to disable scrolling when tab is not full?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a nested tab but I have little bit cosmetic issue. I would like to disable scroll when I have an empty tab.

When you look at the example below, I have two tabs - one of them contains a List and second one contains only a Text widget. Why is possible scroll also second tab? I would scroll only when is necessary.

```dart
DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Center(
                child: Text("Header")
                ),
            ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.red,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
                    tabs: [Text("Tab 1"), Text("Tab 2")]))
        ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
            children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 150,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text("item");
                    }),
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text("One item");
                    }),
            ],
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `ListView` issue. By default, `ListView` will take up all available space on the screen and will be always scrollable. If this is not the desired behavior, you can set the following on it:

```dart
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  primary: false,
  // ...
);
```

Comment: That does not work. I want scroll the appbar only when is it necessary. When I tried set shrinkWrap then listview doesn't scrolling with the appbar.